# Stored Image not showing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, storage

I am uploading and storing image using Laravel, but whenever I try to show it, it replies with 404 not found.

```
public function uploadPhoto(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'doc_photo' => 'file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,webp|max:2048'
    ]);

    $user_id = $request->input('user_id1');
    $userModel = User::find($user_id);
    
    if($request->has('user_photo')){

        $photo_file = $request->file('user_photo');
        $photo_filename = 'dp_' . $user_id . '.' . $photo_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $photo_path = $photo_file->storeAs('DP', $photo_filename);
        $userModel->display_image_path = $photo_path;

    }

    $result = $userModel->save();
    toastr()->success("Photo Uploaded", "Success");
    
    return back();

}
```

and my config/filesystems.php looks like

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and upon showing it in html page, i get this error.

> GET http://xyzdomian.com/storage/app/DP/dp_4.png 404 (Not Found)

If i physically check into the folder,the file is created but still getting 404 not found.
Please guide me resolving this issue.

Comment: Have you run `php artisan storage:link` already to create symlinks?

Comment: Make you you create the symbolic link as `php artisan storage:link` then your url would be `http://xyzdomian.com/storage/DP/dp_4.png` if you save your image on `/storage/app/public/DP/dp_4.png`

Answer (score 0):

Change in **Controller**

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'user_photo' => 'sometimes|required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg|max:5000',
]);

if($request->hasFile('user_photo')){
  $photo_file = $request->file('user_photo');
  $photo_filename = 'dp_' . $user_id . '.' . $photo_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $photo_path = $request->file('user_photo')->move(public_path('DP/'), $photo_filename);//Your image save in public/DP folder
  $userModel->display_image_path = $photo_path;
}
```

Change your `config/filesystems.php`

```
'local' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
           'driver' => 'local',
           'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
           'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
           'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```